# How to rotate object not from it's center point but from it's another point?

Tags: unity, rotation

I am new in unity and I am developing a game where I want to rotate my object I try this code for it.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            LastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if(LastMousePosition.y> 112){
            Bow.Rotate(Vector3.up*(Input.mousePosition.y - LastMousePosition.y));
        }
        else if(LastMousePosition.y<112){
            Bow.Rotate(Vector3.down*(Input.mousePosition.y - LastMousePosition.y));
        }
        LastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

It works fine for me but my object is rotate from It's center point and I want to rotate it from another point can any one help me with this?

Comment: translate your local matrix to the "otherpoint"

Comment: How to do that? Any sample code will help me a lot.

Comment: Saying you're new to Unity and advertising a Unity consulting company is a strange combination. Please don't advertise on this site, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an empty gameobject, make it child of your gameobject. Move it to one of the corners you want to rotate about, Use [RotateAround](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) to rotate your gameobject. You could also do the same through code by calculating the dimensions of your gameobject.

Edit: You could use these scripts to make your life easier: [PivotManager](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/PivotManager), [SetPivot](http://solvethesystem.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/solving-the-pivot-problem-in-unity/).

Comment: Thanks for help it works for me. [Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)